# mysql pivot table with concat AND pivot counting of selected rows

Tags: mysql, pivot, concatenation

I have the following mysql-table `cars` layout

```
BRAND   | TYPE  | COLOR
-----------------------
bmw     | e30   | red
bmw     | e90   | blue
bmw     | e12   | red
audi    | a3    | green
bmw     | e90   | red
audi    | tt    | blue
bmw     | e12   | blue
audi    | a3    | green
```

And want to have a pivot table as result with the following layout:

```
brand_type  | red   | blue  | green | total 
-------------------------------------------
bmw-e30     | 1     | 0     | 0     | 1
bmw-e90     | 1     | 1     | 0     | 2
bmw-e12     | 1     | 1     | 0     | 2
audi-a3     | 0     | 0     | 2     | 2
audi-tt     | 0     | 1     | 1     | 2
```

The farest I could achive was this query:

```
SELECT brand, 
    sum(if(color = 'red', 1, 0)) as red, 
    sum(if(color = 'blue', 1, 0)) as blue, 
    sum(if(color = 'green', 1,0)) as green,
    count(color) as total
FROM `cars` group by brand;
```

With this result:

```
brand   | red   | blue  | green | total 
-------------------------------------------
bmw     | 3     | 2     | 0     | 5
audi    | 0     | 1     | 3     | 4
```

I searched already in the net, but I could not find any solution where 2 columns ( brand and type ) are concated
**AND** used in the pivot result

**1. How can I achive my desired pivot table result?** Solved with the hint of @kevinsjöberg

```
SELECT concat(brand, '-', type) as BT, 
    sum(if(color = 'red', 1, 0)) as red, 
    sum(if(color = 'blue', 1, 0)) as blue, 
    sum(if(color = 'green', 1,0)) as green,
    count(color) as total
FROM `cars` group by BT;
```

[removed second question, as it is solved with the first answer already]

Comment: Why do you want brand/type tp be a single column?

Comment: I just don't understand why you want to do this. Generally issues of data display are much more simply and effectively handled at the application level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function from MySQL.

```
CONCAT(`BRAND`, '-', `TYPE`)
```

You then GROUP BY `brand` and `type`.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d3db/2

Comment: Just concatnation is easy :) But I need to get the colors counted for these concanated column... how do I achive this?

Comment: Your example somehow does not show all possible combinations, some which exists in the table, are not shown and withit not counted. For some reason....

Comment: Yep worked, I could achive this as well by using the new columnwith `concat(brand, '-', type) as BT` and `group by BT`. Question 1, solved. Thanks

Comment: Can I mark two as answered? As I have two questions?

Comment: No, only one post can be marked as answered. As for your second question, I'm not entirely sure what you're after. The SQL-query provided in the fiddle will work with any brand or type.

Comment: rethinking my second question, it makes no sense, as the brand and type will be created dynamically. Your answer solve the problem.