# Mysql query to summarized (Pivot) table by Row Values

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like of employee allowances like this:

| ID | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Allowance 1 | 200 |
| 15 | Allowance 2 | 120 |
| 10 | Allowance 2 | 130 |

I am attempting to query a pivot output like so:

| ID | Allowance 1 | Allowance 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 200 | 130 |
| 15 | 0 | 120 |

I tried this solution here: [mysql pivot table with concat AND pivot counting of selected rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942200/mysql-pivot-table-with-concat-and-pivot-counting-of-selected-rows)
This works if I know the various allowances in the table, in my case I don't, any employee can have any allowance and users can add as many allowances as they want.

How can I achieve this so that the query can dynamically get all Allowances into columns and employees id in rows

Comment: So you need a *dynamic pivot*; sounds like with a dataset that could have 1 row with 50 columns and 1 row with 1 column the rest NULL, this is more suited as a task for your client or reporting application.

Comment: You are right @Stu and that is how I am currently achieving it but with around 20\k employees and a couple of allowances each, its taking too long because I am having to loop through the employee. Trying to find a way to make it much faster